# How to implement LinkedIn Authentication using Firebase Functions and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, linkedin-api

I wanted to create an authentication for users using LinkedIn OAuth API and Firebase in my Android Application, but there are no options for direct authentication in Firebase Auth, but I found a solution from GitHub which was using Firebase Functions and Node.js

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth

I tried using this solution but after putting in the credentials in the linkedIn popup and clicking on submit button the error shows up saying "Error in the token Function: undefined" and in firebase console log it says "Function finished with status: 'crash'".

[LinkedIn Auth Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhGna.png)

[Firebase Console log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkO4s.png)